# Preserve sub-foldings on any level when folding/unfolding the mother ones in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I need to preserve the sub-foldings on folding/unfolding the mother (super) ones.
I'm using SublimeText 3.

---

**Illustrative Example**

Let's say that we have the following unfolded code [***Image-1***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Iqn.png). And I need to fold the following marked ones [***Image-2***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seayb.png) to be like this [***Image-3***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j95aI.png). When I fold the super (mother) lines like this [***Image-4***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc88z.png), then unfold them like this [***Image-5***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Iqn.png), I find all sub-foldings lost. What I'm looking for is to preserve the sub-foldings at any level however I fold/unfold the mother ones.

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/preserve-sub-foldings-on-any-level-when-folding-unfolding-the-mother-ones/24265

Comment: @KeithHall I've posted similar post on sublime forum.